# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer does not always show all test cases

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Pro with MSTest for unit tests. I have noticed something very odd in the Test Explorer.

If I run a test that has a datasource containing several test cases and they all pass, the Test Explorer will sometimes show only one test case in the results pane on the RH side, and sometimes it will show *all* the test cases individually as having passed. Repeatedly running the test will alternate between the two outputs.

Is this a bug in Test Explorer, or is something very clever going on that I haven't tumbled to?

TIA

Comment: What is the data being fed via the datasource? As in, is it simple data that is passed as arguments into method being tested? If so, you could try experimenting with `XUnit`, specifically the `[Theory]` attribute, which allows you to pass multiple input into a signle test, similar to datasource. That way you could check whether Test Explorer was behaving any differently regards the `XUnit` tests. You will need extension for MSTest to execute XUnit tests though, so install that too.

Comment: It's just a CSV text file, one row per testcase. We have >12500 tests, so changing to XUnit isn't really an option at this stage.  I'm just curious if anyone else has noticed this phenomenon. I don't know if it is just running one test case from the datasource, or just displaying one result.

Comment: Ah OK. I wouldn't change anything in that case. Would be too much work.